# validate =false not validating on button click

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have 2 textboxes called minimum version and maximum version requesting user to enter Version ( like 1.3.4 ). At a given time only one can be blank, not both So I have provided custom field validator .Also I have provided regular expression to validate if values entered are proper.

When I click on button entering invalid version field I can see button click event is getting triggered. Could you please help.

```
   <asp:Label ID="lblMinimum" runat="server" Text="Minimum Version : " CssClass="alignLeft"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMinimumVersion" runat="server" Width="312px" CssClass="alignRight" ValidationGroup="validate"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revModuleVersion" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMinimumVersion"
            ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d+)+$" ErrorMessage="* Please enter valid version number"  ValidationGroup="validate"/> 


       <asp:Label ID="lblMaximum" runat="server" Text="Maximum Version : " CssClass="alignLeft"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaximumVersion" runat="server" Width="312px" CssClass="alignRight" ValidationGroup="validate"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMaximumVersion"
            ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d+)+$" ErrorMessage="* Please enter valid version number" ValidationGroup="validate"/>


     <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateNow" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Text="Create now"
            OnClick="btnCreateNow_Click" CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="validate"></asp:Button> 

   <asp:CustomValidator ID="custValidateModuleVersion" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Maximum version should be greather or equal to Minimum version"
OnServerValidate="custValidateModuleVersion_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>   

    <asp:CustomValidator ID="custValidate" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="* Please enter atleast one version"
OnServerValidate="CustomValidator_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Your button `btnUpdateNow` is not validating the form because it has `CausesValidation="false"`

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned CausesValidation = "false". Make it as true or remove it

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdateNow" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Text="Create now" OnClick="btnCreateNow_Click"  ValidationGroup="validate"></asp:Button>
```

1. The CausesValidation property specifies if a page is validated when a Button control is clicked.
2. Page validation is performed when a button is clicked by default.
3. This property is mostly used to prevent validation when a cancel or reset button is clicked.